# bitbucket mercurial don't show username properly

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I have my private repository and do commit from my machine. In my hgrc file i have sth like this

```
[ui]
username = John <jon@mail.com>
```

In my bucket account I have the same mail and firstname set to John.
Now i do commit and under overview tab I have totally different name. How I can fix it?
Best regards

Comment: What do you mean by 'totally different name'? If bitbucket can match a commiter to a bb user, it'll use the latter name.

Comment: I have artu in bitbucket. I am woundering from where it comes and how to change it

Answer (score 4):

When you clone from BitBucket it prepends the site with the current logged in username. For example, instead of cloning from `https://bitbucket.org/dls/commit-msg-check` it will clone from `https://dls@bitbucket.org/dls/commit-msg-check`. Note the **dls@** in the second url.

If your local .hgrc or Mercurial.ini files have a different user name in them, BitBucket gets (rightfully) confused. This is how BitBucket shows you that it's confused:

[image: BitBucket User Confusion]

Notice the question marks next to the username. Hovering over them shows "Author not mapped to BitBucket user" help text.

If you're using OpenID to sign into BitBucket, then it would make sense that your username is Artur (the same username that you've used to sign into StackOverflow, I see). In this case, you can check out [this link](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+up+User+Aliasing+for+your+Repositories) to learn about setting up aliases in BitBucket.